# groovysh not working in Groovy version 2.2.0

Tags: groovy

I recently downloaded and installed the Groovy-2.2.0 windows binary, configured my system, i.e., Java is installed and functioning properly, etc. My GROOVY_HOME variable is set to C:\groovy-2.2.0, my path is set to C:\groovy-2.2.0\bin and C:\groovy-2.2.0\lib. However, unlike Groovy 2.1.9, the groovysh command generates a flood of errors (too long to post here) about an inability to run groovystarter. I'm using a WinXP (sp3) machine with Groovy-2.2.0 installed. Oddly, I can compile and run groovy programs. It is only the groovy shell that isn't functioning.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a few helpful individuals, i.e., Guillaume, Cédric, and Pascal, the posted issue has been solved. There was a subfolder in my root directory, C:\, named C:\jline. I copied its contents to an unused subdirectory (as a backup) then deleted the C:\jline folder. After doing so, the groovysh command worked perfectly. I felt compelled to post the solution in the event another programmer experienced the same or perhaps highly similar and related problem.

~Caitlin